# different time zone server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, timezone

I have a server with ls ubuntu 12.04 apache2 and mysql.

I have two sites on this server, example.com and example.org. The example.com is a site for a country that has timezone -4 (UTC-4) and example.org for a country with time zone -3 (UTC-3)​​. These sites present data bases in time. To be more friendly, I would like the example.com example.org sites and worked with their local schedules.

Is there any way of setting different time zones for sites (directories or files) on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way to set the server time itself to be different on different directories.

However, Apache does have a way for you to set the timezone, via the [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) directive.  specifically, `SetEnv America/New_York`. You could set this for each of your Virtual Hosts, and hopefully that will clear up your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No; have the server use UTC and let the application convert the times.